# VB6 read only project file

Tags: vb6, ide, project

I just started using tfs 2012 as source control for my VB6 projects. 
When I run the project from the VB6 IDE I get a File/Path access error to the VB6 project file. The reason for this is that it is not checked out, and therefore read-only. 
This seems to be a common problem (with or without source control): when running a VB6 project from the IDE, the IDE tries to make the vbp file writable. For no reason, since it doesn't make any changes to it.
Is there any way to prevent the IDE from trying the make the file writable? If not, is it possible to auto-checkout a file in VB6 if it is being edited, either by the IDE runtime or if I make changes to it?

thanks

Comment: I'm using VB6 the same way. My team's answer is to either click "No" when prompted to save the group and or project. Or to clear those files from the selected files before clicking "Yes". All our changes to the project or group are checked out and performed on the build server. We will also mark the project, and group files as read / write but be careful NOT to check them back into TFS.

Comment: ... that or use TFS Local Workspace.

Comment: The VB6 IDE will routinely make changes to the VBP automatically. In particular, paths to COM references, but other things also. This is a normal (if annoying) part of how it functions.